# Make table set height and width with rowspans... Won't work

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having this little table of mine, which doesn't seem to work. The CSS will tell all about what height and width I want. Do I do this in a wrong way or what am I missing in this?

And why aren't all the borders aligned?

The table, html and CSS can be seen in this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YaKCT/

```
<table class="stamtavle">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=7 class="cell1"><p>Volstrups Casillas</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=3 class="cell2"><p>Colman</p></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell3"><p>Carthago Z</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell3"><p>Rosenquarz</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td rowspan=3 class="cell2"><p>Lucille</p></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td class="cell3"><p>Lordship</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td class="cell3"><p>Carna</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td rowspan=7 class="cell1"><p>Volstrups Corona</p></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=3 class="cell2"><p>Churchill</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell2"><p>Cicero</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell3"><p>Ziska</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=3 class="cell2"><p>Volstrups Cartia</p></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell3"><p>Calato Z</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell3"><p>Sidsel</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `.stamtavle table` is wrong, should be `.stamtavle` http://jsfiddle.net/YaKCT/1/

Comment: @Mr.Alien  got it, your link might not be updated though - try  - http://jsfiddle.net/Zn9ep/1/

Comment: @RobSedgwick thanks a lot, I don't know how I missed that :)

Comment: Thx for your reply, but i doesn't seem to work. I've changed the heights a bit - but in proportion to each other - but that doesnt seem to work either...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zn9ep/2/

Here's the fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your table tag

class="stamtavle" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"

I think you'd need a different approach to make the spacing between cells work how it was before due to your rowspan layout. This does neaten everything up though.